# gembox.spreadsheet date gets converted to int

Tags: excel, date, int, spreadsheet, gembox-spreadsheet

I am loading an Excel 97-2003 XLS file into C# using GemBox.Spreadsheet version 39.3.30.1202.

One cell has the value 13-01-2017 (Formatted: 20170113) and the datatype "Date" with custom formatting "YYYYMMDD".

After 
`Gembox.Load(new XlsLoadOptions( ) { PreserveOptions = XlsOptions.None });`

The cell has the value 42748 and valuetype 'int'.

I can get the correct value using `ExcelCell.ConvertExcelNumberToDateTime(cell.DoubleValue, false)`
= {13/01/2017 00:00:00}, but since this is donw in an automated process I wouldn't be able to tell real integers from the wrongfylly converted date.

How can i get GemBox.Spreadsheet to see that the date is not a number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was (hot)fixed in GemBox.SpreadSheet 39.3.30.1205 nuget